# How to show portrait mode when holding in landscape and landscape when holding in portrait

Tags: android, rotation, android-orientation

My goal is to make an Android app that displays traditional Mongolian. However, Mongolian is displayed vertically, even though the font writes it horizontally like English. Thus, if I print it on the screen in portrait mode I have to hold the phone as if it were in landscape mode in order to read it properly (and vice versa).

I've seen a lot of questions about forcing it into one mode or another by adding a line like one the following to the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

but I want to dynamically switch between both orientations, just opposite from what you would normally want.

If there is a better solution, then I am open to that, too. I've tried things like setting

```
android:rotation="90"
```

in the view's xml, but it wasn't displaying correctly for even one view, let alone multiple view objects. I also saw solutions for rotating individual views with canvas, but that seemed more complex than just reversing the orientation, since everything needs to be rotated (including TextViews, Buttons, ListViews, etc.)

UPDATE: I finally chose an answer because I wasn't getting any other answers. I'm still not sure how to implement it. My plan now is just to allow users to select a fixed orientation in settings.

Comment: Maybe just write a newline after every character?

Comment: Adding a newline is a good thought, but unfortunately traditional Mongolian is like cursive in English. The letters are all connected, so it actually has to be rotated. (example text http://www.studymongolian.net/lessons/lesson-2/#key-sentences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change orientatio, from within your activity call:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

or

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

to catch orientation event implement `onConfigurationChange()` and add orientation to you configration in manifest

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried doing this, but setting the orientation to portrait if Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE is true (and vise versa), then this causes onConfigurationChange() to be called again and again flipping the orientation back and forth.

Comment: You can set a flag to know if changing is coming from you or not, and implement `onConfigurationChange()` based on that flag

Answer (score 0):

```
final int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
```

then, Use this where you want to switch orientation:

```
switch(orientation) {
   case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
       setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
       break;
   case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
       setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
       break;                   
}
```

Comment: Android docs says that getOrientation() was depricated as of API level 8 in favor of getRotation(). (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getOrientation()) I'm currently looking into how and when I could use getRotation to implement this.

Comment: The setRequestedOrientation seems to make the orientation permanent (so when I manually rotate my phone it stays in the same orientation). How would I make it automatically flip to the other orientation as I rotate my phone?